# How to get an action URL in Kohana 3?

Tags: controller, action, kohana-3

Is there an official method or helper that I can use to get an URL of an action in a view?

For example, I like to get a URL of /controller/action1 when I'm in a view of /controller/action0.

I know that I can use the following code, but I wonder if it is already in Kohana's core.

```
function getControllerActionURL($controller,$action)
{
   return URL::site(false,true).$controller."/".$action;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**1**.Get URI using **route name**:

```
 $uri = Route::get('routename')
     ->uri(array(
           'controller' => $controller, 
           'action' => $action
          ));
```

**2a**.Get URI using **main route**:

```
 $uri = Request::instance()
     ->uri(array(
           'controller' => $controller,
           'action'     => $action
 ));
```

**2b**.The same with **current route**:

```
 $uri = Request::current()
     ->uri(array(
           'controller' => $controller,
           'action'     => $action
 ));
```

**2c**. `Request::uri()` uses current route params by default, so if you want to change only `action` (or `id` etc), you can **skip current params**:

```
 $uri = Request::instance() // or Request::current()
     ->uri(array(
           'action'     => $action
 ));
```

Passing only an `action`, we ask `Request` to use its current values (`$this->controller` for controller name, `$this->directory` for directory etc)

PS. Read [this](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#creating-urls-and-links-using-routes).

PPS. In Kohana **v3.2** `Request::uri()` call returns a **current URI**, so you need to call `Request::current()->route()->uri(...)`;